# Image change style when only have source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change image height only when its src is not empty 
with JQuery or JavaScript , i have an image that have fixed height and in chrome they always keep blank place for it even when there is no source for it i want show this height only when image have source

Comment: if an answer solved the issue you should mark it as accepted

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is not necessary, just use css to define a zero height for images with an empty `src` attribute:

```
img[src=""] {
    height: 0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```css
  img[src=""] {
     display: none;
  }
```

You can change the height or not display it..

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use javascript instead of CSS, you can try calling this function whenever you want to check if the image has a source / display the image.

Set an ID for your image and then:

```
function check()
  {
    if (document.getElementById("yourimgidhere").src == "")
      {
        document.getElementById("yourimgidhere").style.display = "none";
      }
      else
      {
        document.getElementById("yourimgidhere").style.display = "inline";
      }
  }
```

The CSS method is far more effective and is the proper way of doing it as other people have answered, but this should work too.